# importing java libraries into dot os source

Tags: android, android-source, lineageos

Hey I'm building dotOS rom for samsung grand prime. Im stuck with an error.
the

```
device/samsung/qcom-common/doze/doze/Android.mk: error: SamsungDoze (APPS android-arm) missing org.lineageos.platform.internal (JAVA_LIBRARIES android-arm) You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is intentional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
```

So I went down to device/samsung/qcom-common/doze/doze/Android.mk and found out

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
org.lineageos.platform.internal
```

I downloaded the package org.lineageos.platform.internal but how do I make the android.mk look into the local directory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For me, just cloning the LineageOS SDK worked great.

Answer (score -1):

This is the library from LineageOS SDK which dotOS doesn't have. You will need to adapt the device sources to not use any LineageSDK dependencies. Check official sources of other devices.